# GridSearchCV Lasso warnings ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to find the best params for my data using CVGridSearch

```
lasso = Lasso(random_state=0)
alphas = [0.5, 0.1 , 0.01 ]
max_iter = [1000, 2000, 3000]
tuned_parameters = [{'alpha': alphas , 'max_iter' : max_iter}]
n_folds = 5
clf = GridSearchCV(lasso, tuned_parameters, cv=n_folds, refit=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

When I run the code, it shows me following warnings

```
Best: 0.999998 using {'alpha': 0.1, 'max_iter': 1000}
Best: -2028.743734 using {'alpha': 0.1, 'max_iter': 1000}
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:492: 
ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to 
increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha 
may cause precision problems.
ConvergenceWarning)
Best: -2241.410408 using {'alpha': 0.01, 'max_iter': 1000}
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:492: 
ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to 
increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha 
 may cause precision problems.
```

When the best score 0.999998 is found, why the CVGridsearch doesn't stop?

Comment: Show the full code. The output you are showing is not produced by the above code.